# Apex of an Exponential Function

Tags: exponential-function, curvature

Is there a way of calculating where the apex of an exponential lies? There's probably a deeper / more mathematical way of explaining what this is exactly. The image hopefully demonstrates what I mean. I'm not sure if derivatives help and perhaps numerical methods need to be used?

[image: Exponential]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compute the maximum of the [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) of the curve $y=e^x$. This can be done by the formula 
$$\kappa=\frac{y''}{(1+(y')^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{e^x}{(1+e^{2x})^{3/2}}.$$
A simple computation shows that this is maximal for $x=-\frac{\ln 2}{2}$ (after edit).

However, for the function $A\,e^{Bx}$ where $A,B>0$, the result may be different and the computed quantity is not invariant with respect to the "scaling" of your graph. Note that you have a different scale in the $x$- and $y$-axis in your picture.

By a "measurement on the screen" it seems to me that your 4 units on the $x$-axis correspond to $100$ on the $y$-axis in your graph. So you really draw the function $\frac{1}{25} e^x$ (using an equi-scaled graph) which leads to the maximal curvature in $\frac{-\ln 2}{2}+\ln 25\simeq 2.87$ which is already approximately 3 as you want.

Comment: Thanks Peter - I see that that answer gives $ x \approx -0.5 $ but I would have thought $ x \in [3,4] $ from my figure. Perhaps Curvature isn't the definition I'm after?

Comment: But note that you use a very different scale in your $x$- and $y$-axis (in your picture). "Rescaling" is not an invariant operation in these considerations -- which is the reason why such "apex" is not a very natural definition. FYI: look how the exponential looks like if you change the scale like this... :-) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28x%29%2C+x+from+-100+to+100

Comment: @hgeop I added more explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If we look for  the maximum of the curvature of the curve $y=e^{ax}$, we have $$\kappa=\frac{y''}{(1+(y')^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{a^2 e^{a x}}{\left(1+a^2 e^{2 a x}\right)^{3/2}}$$ $$\frac{d\kappa}{dx}=\frac{a^3e^{ax}(1-2a^2e^{2ax})}{\left(1+a^2 e^{2 a x}\right)^{5/2}}$$ So, the maximum curvature is obtained for $$x=-\frac{\log(2a^2)}{2a}$$ for which  $$\kappa=\frac{2 a}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$ At this point, the second derivative $$\frac{d^2\kappa}{dx^2}=\frac{a^4 e^{a x} \left(4 a^4 e^{4 a x}-10 a^2 e^{2 a x}+1\right)}{\left(1+a^2 e^{2 a
   x}\right)^{7/2}}=-\frac{8 a^3}{9 \sqrt{3}}$$ confirms the fact that it is a maximum.

For $a=1$, the maximum curvature would happen at $x=-\frac{\log (2)}{2}$.

But, as you say, may be the maximum curvature is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I guess exponential is too crazy for that kind of stuff - it's growing - well, exponentially - so basically, always growing more than ever before - not just getting bigger - but getting more bigger than it ever got bigger before. All I'm saying is that the derivative always grows, i.e. that the second derivative is positive. Problem is, all derivatives are positive anyway ... So it's also getting more more bigger than it ever got more bigger before, and so on ...

At the end of the day, such apexes as searched are everywhere, given that the slope is always steeper after any point than it was before, by a margin that was never so great before, ...

Comment: I don't think that the "approximately 3" that he observes cannot be explained. If "everybody can see it", it can also be computed (see the end of my answer).

Comment: Well you computed the point of maximum curvature - but whether this is the apex @hgeop was looking for remains to be seen. Now, you said yourself that it depends on A and B factors. I'd wager that for every point P on the curve, we can find a set-up of x and y scaling (function of A and B) that make P "look like" an hgeop-apex.

Comment: yes, in this point, I agree with you.